# Ответ 403 при get запросе

Tags: python, requests

Пытаюсь получить изображение с сайта. Приходит ответ:

```
<Response [403]>
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>DDOS-GUARD</title><meta charset="utf-8">
```

Как можно обойти это?

```
import requests

URL = 'https://cbr.ru/legacy/PhotoStore/img/5109-0128r.jpg'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36'}

result = requests.session().get(URL, headers=headers)
print(result)
print(result.content.decode())
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Помогло добавление в headers:

```
    'cookes': 'erhfuiwhgfiuwerhiw4ueghfwoqghuyq4go7w4gfuier'
```